# How to test faster GUI applications?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, gui-testing

I'd like to know to test faster my GUI applications.

For the backend I got a good set of unit-tests, so I think that's quite ok and I can iterate quite fast.

But to test the frontend logic I find myself running over and over repeating the same sequence of events to test certain part of the logic... and that feels like I'm doing something clearly wrong here because my iteration cycle is not as faster as I'd like it to.

So, could you suggest me a good way to test GUI applications? in particular I'm pretty much interested to know how to speed-up my PyQt apps testing cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to validate that certain GUI actions do the correct thing, you can use [`QTest`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtest.html) to simulate button clicks and other GUI interaction.

Ideally, most of your business logic is in non-GUI modules to make it easier to test.  That way, GUI testing is limited mostly to testing if the results display correctly and that key presses trigger events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give it a shot to QTest. And you're right, the business logic should be isolated from GUI completely.  I had made a question about that [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331246/how-to-decouple-ui-from-logic-on-pyqt-qt-apps-properly)

Answer (score 1):

There are also UI blackbox testing tools such as [AutoPilot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing/Autopilot) and [Squish](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) which allow you to record your interactions with the application and later on replay them again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using windows so I'm not sure whether I can use those ones, anyway, +1 for the effort

Comment: I would be surprised if AutoPilot didn't also work on Windows, but Squish definitely does. It even has support for testing applications usign Windows specific technologies such as MFC

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) should be good for PyQt5 now (using `backend="uia"` released in November, 2016).